# Connecting to hdfs from kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hdfs, minikube

I am trying to connect to the hdfs cluster from a Docker image deployed in miniKube. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM lrh7
USER root
ARG config_files=configs
ARG pyfiles=pyfiles
ARG HADOOP_PATH="/opt/hadoop"

RUN mkdir -p ${HADOOP_PATH}


RUN yum -y install which java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 krb5-workstation python3

COPY hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop ${HADOOP_PATH}/etc/hadoop
COPY hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs ${HADOOP_PATH}/share/hadoop/hdfs
COPY hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common ${HADOOP_PATH}/share/hadoop/common
COPY hadoop-2.6.0/bin ${HADOOP_PATH}/bin
COPY hadoop-2.6.0/libexec ${HADOOP_PATH}/libexec


RUN mkdir -p ${HADOOP_PATH}/work-dir && \
    rm /bin/sh && \
    ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd

RUN chmod -R 777 ${HADOOP_PATH}

RUN pip3 install flask gunicorn 

ENV HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_PATH}

COPY ${config_files}/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
COPY ${config_files}/core-site.xml ${HADOOP_PATH}/etc/hadoop
COPY ${config_files}/hdfs-site.xml ${HADOOP_PATH}/etc/hadoop
COPY ${config_files}/hive-site.xml ${HADOOP_PATH}/etc/hadoop
COPY ${config_files}/krb5cc_0 /tmp



COPY ${pyfiles}/app.py ${HADOOP_PATH}/work-dir 
COPY ${pyfiles}/config.py ${HADOOP_PATH}/work-dir 

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
ENV PATH="$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"


WORKDIR ${HADOOP_PATH}/work-dir

ENV PORT 8080
```

I can build and run an image using this Dockerfile. Using this image I can also connect to hdfs and run hdfs commands. For the next step I deployed this image in minikube using the below deploy.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hdfsclient
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hdfsclient
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hdfsclient
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hdfsclient
        image: hdfsclient
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

and in the app.py I have:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
import config
app = Flask(__name__)

filename='tmp2.file'
f = open(filename,'w')
f.write('Hello World!')
f.close()

@app.route("/")
def hello():    
    os.system(f'hdfs dfs -put -f {filename} /tmp/{filename}')
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=config.PORT, debug=config.DEBUG_MODE)
```

Basically I am writing a dummy file to the hdfs location.

The deployment is successful and pod is created. I also created a service. However, no file is written to the hdfs location.

What is the problem and also is there a better way to do this? I want to be able to read and write to hdfs location using minikube.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? Your `app.py` is located in the `hdfsclient` image and your server that you want to send files to is located outside? Does the `app.py` script is starting? Please provide output of the command `$ kubectl get pods ` and `$ kubectl describe pod hdfsclient`

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. I could made it work by adding ‘ENTRYPOINT [“gunicorn”,”app:app”,”—config=config.py”]’ to the end of Dockerfile. Now we can go to the 2nd part of the question which is if there is a better way to do this. Thanks